# Why is the codimension of an algebraic set defined by $r$ equations at most $r$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have $r$ polynomials $g_1, ..., g_r$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, ..., x_n]$.
And let $H = \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n : g_i(\mathbf{x}) = 0 (1 \leq i \leq r) \}$.

I was wondering why it then follows that the codimension of $H$ is at most $r$.
It seems like it should be simple, but I am stuck on this at the moment. 
I would greatly appreciate any thing that would help me understand this. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not that simple — it's a special case (in the sense that the ring is a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{C}$) of Krull's (generalized) Hauptidealsatz. A proof should be in every commutative algebra textbook. In this particular case I think the proof is a bit nicer — you can probably see it in Mumford's Red Book.

Comment: I think it's in Section 6 of Shafarevich's Basic AG I, though I don't have it on hand to check.  I believe he tells you the algebraic codimension (what Hoot is referring to) is the analytic codimension (which is I guess what you are asking).  It should also be in Griffiths & Harris, if you like that style.

Comment: If you know that the dimension of a variety is the generic value of the dimension of its Zariski tangent spaces, then this is clear: each equation reduces the dimension of the Zariski tangent space at a point by at most $1$.

Comment: @Hoot I was wondering does what I asked follow relatively easily from Krull's Hauptidealsatz?

Comment: @JohnnyT. The codimension of $H$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$ is exactly the codimension (what is also called height or rank) of the ideal $(g_1, \dots, g_r)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$. I guess it depends a little on how you define codimension.

Comment: @Hoot I guess the definition I had in mind was that codim of $H$ is n - krull dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n] / (g_1, ..., g_r)$. Would it be relatively easy to show this is equal to the  height of $(g_1, ..., g_r)$ assuming Krull's Hauptidealsatz?

Comment: This is somehow the "wrong" definition of codimension. It should work out the same for varieties but it's another theorem -- see Hartshorne I.1.8A

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. May I assume that the definition you gave me works even when $(g_1, ..., g_r)$ is not prime (or when $H$ is not irreducible)?